# SSRS - Move/Shift stepped line chart

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

Using SSRS, is it possible to shift the stepped line chart(blue coloured) slightly to the left so as to align them with respect to the bar charts below it.
[image]

Comment: You can achieve that changing the x-axis to qualitative values (1,2,3,4...) then just substract/add to the first/last value half width of your bar (0,4 if default value is set). If that is a possible solution for you let me know.

Comment: Assuming you are using a date format you can achieve a similar effect using a `DateAdd` expression to your category values, by subtracting 15 days from the dates you are reporting on.

Comment: @Jonnus- I tried subtracting 15 days by going on the Series properties of the stepped line chart and adding the following expression on the category field <DateAdd("d", -15, Fields!Reporting_Month.Value)>, but that didn't work. All the data on the reports were stacked onto the right after doing that. Do I need to make additional changes.

Comment: @Jonnus - I managed to align the stepped line chart by subtracting 15 days and changing x axis type to scalar. However, for the month Dec, the stepped line chart ended at the start, but I'd want it to go across Dec as well.

Comment: @sykonba to extend the values across December you will need to effectively create a dummy record for January (max month +1) with the same value add for December.

Comment: @Jonnus- Is there anyway that I can only specify in the Series properties of the stepped line chart, maybe create an IIf condition in the category field.